# How to get logged in username of Jenkins in parameter's Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins parameter, I'm writing Groovy script and in that script I need to pass Jenkins logged in username NOT user. User and username, could be different

Ex - User, that is displayed left to 'log out', could be - Bob Gill and username, used to login - could be - bob

User can be retrieved using `User.current()`. Please tell me how to get username.

**NOTE** I don't need username in pipeline code. I need it in Groovy script of parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I could retrieve it with following -

```
import hudson.model.User

def userName = User.current().getId()
```